# SQLite Calendar Week starting

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I noticed SQLite and c# (.NET) have different calendar week calculation.

The 01.01.2021 is not calendaring week 1 in c# / .net but for SQLite it is.
For my program, I need the calculation of c#/.net in SQLite. Is there a way I can change it?

All data is stored as DATETIME in a local SQLite database. The weeknumber is requested by following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Zeit` 
WHERE strftime('%Y',`startzeit`) = "2021" 
AND strftime('%W',date(`startzeit`, '+7 days')) = "01" 
ORDER BY `startzeit` DESC
```

Comment: More context please. How are your dates stored?

Comment: Sorry, data is stored in a local database as DATETIME, following SQL is executed: SELECT * FROM `Zeit` 
WHERE strftime('%Y',`startzeit`) = "2021" AND strftime('%W',date(`startzeit`, '+7 days')) = "01" ORDER BY `startzeit` DESC

Comment: Don't add that as a comment. Edit your question, adding the information in context

Comment: done, sorry. :)

Comment: There is no one way to number the weeks of the year.  One way in the NET framework is not the same as an ISO week of year which is a very common method.  Which method you need is not clear.